# Does using different kernel versions (dual boot) containing different versions of btrfs with the same btrfs filesystem cause problems?

Tags: filesystems, multi-boot, linux-kernel, btrfs, dualboot

Didn't find any answer in the official wiki: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ

#### Why would I want to do that?

I want to try another distro along side my currently installed distro.

#### Where's the problem?

The additional distro I want to install comes with a much newer kernel which obviously contains newer btrfs.
I fear that once I boot into the newer kernel (or even just boot the live system) and the new btrfs reads my old btrfs filesystem it'll update/alter some things in there which won't work or cause problems as soon as I boot the older kernel (original distro) again.

Answer (score 2):

*Generally*, there should be no issue with this. Although the btrfs code in the kernel may vary significantly the on-disk structure of the filesystem remains the same since it was stabilized.

Newer kernel versions may introduce new features which make the on-disk format incompatible with old kernels - but in that case it will use respective compatibility flags on the disk so the older, incompatible kernel will not mount the disk.
But this shouldn't happen to an existing filesystem unless you update/modify it with `btrfstune`.

If there are any relevant differences in the on-disk format depends on the concrete kernel versions though. So to be safe they should not be *too* wide apart.